# What is the difference in the MOSFET circuit below considering control circuit?

Tags: power-electronics, mosfet-driver

What is the difference in the MOSFET circuit below considering control circuit? What is the charge pump involving? Is it required charge pump for the both the circuit?

[image]

Comment: Sounds like homework to me. What did you study/research so far?

Comment: I haven't done anything till now..But i would like to understand before i do to get better understanding.

Comment: What type of MOSFET is represented by the switch?

Comment: You can consider N-CH MOSFET.

Comment: What exactly turns an N-MOSFET on (= conducting)?

Comment: Yes conducting ..also i would like to understand which circuit required for charge pump and why it is required charge pump and why not required other ckt.

Comment: To understand that difference, first answer my question. You can do that with just a little research.